# Не изменяются расширенные политики аудита?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

Когда в gpedit изменяю расширенную политику аудита (в частности Аудит исп-я привилегий не затрагивающих конф. данные и Аудит исп-я привилегий затрагивающих конф. данные)

после перезапуска gpedit политика не применяется (не настроена).

Gpupdate.exe(gpupdate/force) и перезагрузка сервера не помогает.

auditpol /get /category:"Использование прав" выдает следующий результат:

> "Использование прав, не затрагивающее конфиденциальные данныеБез аудита
>     Другие события использования прав       Без аудита
>     Использование прав, затрагивающее конфиденциальные данныеБез аудита",

что указывает на то, что политика не применилась. Чувствую что-то блочит применение данных политик, но вот понять что, низкий уровень администрирования винды не позволяет.

Windows server 2016.